# Passport js authenticate by url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Express JS and Passport JS for my app.

I want to give a new user the opportunity to automatically login, once, by a specific URL. I can get the user from the database with the information from the URL, so I have an User object (with id, email, hashed password etc.) but I don't know how I can use passport to authenticate the user and login.

I tried executing below function with the user object I got from the database:

```
req.login(user, function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  return res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
});
```

source: http://passportjs.org/guide/login/

But that didn't work. Guess it's just because the user object contains the hashed password... 
Anyone who ever tried this before and can tell me how it works?

Comment: http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/ here you can find how to login with the username password  stategy

Comment: No, I know how to login and logout using forms. I want them to be able to login without any. They will receive a link by mail sometimes and I want them to be logged in automatically After opening that personal link. So I tried putting the user object inside the session, but that did not work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe https://github.com/yarax/passport-url strategy will be useful for you

Base logic is getting argument from url

```
UrlStrategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req, options) {
    var self = this;

    function verified(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return self.redirect(self.failRedirect); } // redirect in fail
        self.success(user, info); // done callback
    }

    this._verify(req.query[this.varName], verified);
};
```

Full example here https://github.com/yarax/passport-url/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Ok it worked. You got us on the right track. We edited the passport local repo and created a strategy to our own needs. But your advice to use a different strategy helped us very well, thanks!

Comment: I formed it as a npm module, so you can use it like a usual node module: npm i passport-url

Answer (score 2):

Heyo, so while @Rax Wunter is totally right, I just saw this question and wanted to say it is NOT A GOOD IDEA to do what you're doing here. You should never be passing a hashed password in a URL string ever. This is a really bad security concern.

What you should do instead is use something like a [JSON Web Token](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/concepts/understanding-jwt.html) (JWT). There are lots of libraries to help with this, but the basic flow goes something like this:

- Wherever you are generating your URL, you'll instead generate a JWT that contains the user ID in it.
- You'll then build a URL that looks like: https://somesite.com/?token=
- On your https://somesite.com endpoint, you'll read in the token, validate it using the JWT library (and a shared secret variable), and this will confirm this token was unmodified (eg: you KNOW this user is who they claim to be).

This strategy above is really great because it means you can *safely* log someone in, in a trusted way, without compromising security or leaking a password hash at all.

Comment: Looks great!! Thanks, we will try to implement this into the strategy.

Comment: If you're looking for a more automated way to handle it, you might wanna check out stormpath: https://stormpath.com (I work there, we do this as a service). Pretty awesome ^^

Comment: Thanks, but we already implemented almost everything, so maybe not the best idea to change from platform now. But thanks anyway, will take a look into it ;) And we just implemented jwt, works great! Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

There is not need of any additional module or passport-strategy for this. Adjust below code according to your use case;

```
router.get('/url/:token', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({token: req.params.token}, (err, user) => {
      req.login(user, {}, function(err) {
          if (err) { console.error(err); }
          else return res.redirect("/home.html");
      });
  });

});
```